# Tomcat AccessControlException : Access Denied for deployed webapp

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat8, tomcat8.5

I am a newbie to tomcat and am trying to deploy a webapp (/test) in Tomcat server , but receiving the below error in localhost logs.

```
  SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup Servlet [AxisServlet] in web application [/test] threw load() exception
    java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "/local/web/tomcat85/webapps/test/WEB-INF/scriptServices" "read")
```

Our firm requires us to use Tomcat 8 with Security Manager enabled. I added the below permissions in catalina.policy file but issue still exists.

````
grant codeBase "file:${catalina.base}/webapps/test/-" {
        permission java.security.AllPermission;
        permission java.io.FilePermission "${catalina.base}${file.separator}webapps${file.separator}test${file.separator}", "read, write, delete";
};
```

and also as below in catalina.policy file
```
grant codeBase "file:${catalina.home}/bin/tomcat-juli.jar" {
        permission java.io.FilePermission
         "${java.home}${file.separator}lib${file.separator}logging.properties", "read";
.....
permission java.io.FilePermission "${catalina.base}${file.separator}webapps${file.separator}test${file.separator}WEB-INF${file.separator}classes${file.separator}logging.properties", "read";
        
        permission java.io.FilePermission "${catalina.base}${file.separator}webapps${file.separator}test${file.separator}WEB-INF${file.separator}scriptServices${file.separator}", "read";
};
```
Please guide me on this.
````

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by providing permission as below:

```
permission java.io.FilePermission "${catalina.base}${file.separator}webapps${file.separator}test${file.separator}WEB-INF${file.separator}scriptServices${file.separator}-", "read";
```

Notice the hyphen at the end.